# Aws cloud formation yaml with multiple java projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm becoming crazy with aws cloud formation and its documentation.
What I'm trying to do is:

1. create multiple java lambda functions projects, for example getUsers and insertUser, with their own template yaml;
2. create a root template yaml to deploy all the stack of single inner projects (i.e. single lambda functions).

For the first question the yaml is something like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  getcounties:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  CodeUri: ./
  Description: Lambda functions that retrieves users
  FunctionName: GetUsersTest
  Handler: "GetUsersHandler.handleRequest"
  MemorySize: 128
  ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 5
  Role: LambdaBasicExecutionRole
  Runtime: java11
  Timeout: 30
```

But I'm not able to perform the second task. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: In case your are trying to achieve something like these [one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/4795997cfbb2dbb693123051c67f25861e6c16a3/aws/solutions/StackSetsResource/Templates/stack-set-template.yaml), [two](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudformation.html#w2ab1c27c22c19b5). then, What is the error/issue, you are facing?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to build the root yaml and I'm bit confused. The inner yaml is ready and it is something like this:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  getcounties:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./
      Description: Lambda functions that retrieves users
      FunctionName: GetUsersTest
      Handler: "GetUsersHandler.handleRequest"
      MemorySize: 128
      ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 5
      Role: LambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Runtime: java11

Comment: Could you add that template to the question so it can be formatted properly?

Comment: Edited the original post, thanks